# UserWarning: The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?

Tags: python, virtualenv

```
D:\anzhuang\anconda\lib\distutils\__init__.py:14: UserWarning: The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?
"The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?")
```

when i install both Python 2 and 3 in my computer and install virtualenv for learning. but when i import some package,i got  this warning like picture show. how to fix this problem?  i don`t know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a warning and will also show up while executing programs which includes the package..  However, to overcome this warning message, I edited the file <"D:....\lib\distutils__init__.py"> and removed the line :-). 
In your case the file is D:\anzhuang\anconda\lib\distutils__init__.py: and line no is 14..